# Images on staging server truncated after Git pull

Tags: image, git, png, workflow

I'm working on a project that involves .png images. My workflow consists of...

1. Pushing the images to a Github repository
2. SSH-ing into a remote staging server
3. Doing a `git pull` to add the images to the
   staging server.

When I inspect the images in Github, they appear fine. However, after I pull them onto the staging server, the bottom of the image appears truncated. The browser fills the bottom of the image with an ugly black placeholder.

Here's how one of the images looks on Github: 
[image]

Here's how the same image looks on my staging server:
[image]

Is there a known issue that could cause .png files to become truncated or corrupted after a Git pull?

Comment: Can you please run `cksum *.png` on your good & bad files? If the files are uncorrupted the `cksum` should match. This is to double check that `git` is the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had to do with web hosting. I was using Bluehost's shared SSL environment, which has a data transfer limit of roughly 110kb. Files larger than that size were being truncated.

Comment: Well spotted. More precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have, on your staging server, a setting like `core.autocrlf=true`.
That would try and convert *all* file EOL (end of line) to LF or CRLF depending on the staging server OS, which won't play so well with binary files like a picture.

See:

- "[git sync with rebase showing other people's files as modified locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20211676/6309)"
- "[Why should I use `core.autocrlf=true` in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2825829/6309)"
- "[Distributing git configuration with the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2354278/6309)"